# How to describe a homomorphism from a fundamental group to a finite group?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $S$ be a connected locally noetherian scheme with $s$ a geometric point of $S$. I read something like this: to give a surjective continuous homomorphism from $\pi_1(S, \bar{s})$ to a finite group $G$ is equivalent to give a connected finite etale covering $X\to S$ equipped with a simply transitive action of $G$ on the fibre $X(\bar{s})$.

I don't really need a rigorous proof of this fact. But I would like know the correspondence. Given a a surjective continuous homomorphism $\pi_1(S,\bar{s})\to G$. Then the kernel of this homomorphism, say $H$, is a normal open subgroup of $\pi_1(S,\bar{s})$ of finite index. Is $H$ the fundamental group of some (connected) finite etale cover $X$ of $S$? Is the quotient $\pi_1(S,\bar{s})/H$ the automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}(X/S)$ of $X$.

On the other hand, given a connected finite etale cover $X\to S$, and a simply transitive action of a finite group $G$ on $X(\bar{s})$, is $G$ isomorphic to $\mathrm{Aut}(X/S)$? This does not seem very true to me.

Comment: Are you happy with the corresponding statement in the topological setting? One way to construct the corresponding cover here is to think of the universal cover as a principal $\pi_1$-bundle and take the associated bundle corresponding to the homomorphism $\pi_1 \to G$. In the other direction, yes, the thing you don't think is true is true.

Comment: As Qiaochu points out, this is correct. What source are you reading for information on $\pi_1$? Try looking at Lei Fu's Etale Cohomology book, or SGA 4.5--they both contain the information you're looking for.

Comment: Dear @AlexYoucis,I am reading the notes by Laurent Lafforgue who taught a course on number theory in Milan this year. I actually have Lei Fu's book, and I did not find answer to my questions. Could you please be more precise?

Comment: Dear @QiaochuYuan, yes, I accept the answer in topological setting. Thanks!